# How Did Obara Sand manage this?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In the final episode of *Game of Thrones* season five, Ellaria and Doran Martell with her daughters, the King of Dorne were seeing off Myrcella, Trystane, Jaime and Bronn who were leaving for Kings Landing.

The last season left off at the sequence where Myrcella falls, and then Ellaria is shown bleeding from her nose, due to the poison she used to kill her.

Now in the season 6 premiere, we see Jaime arriving in Kings Landing (it is right now almost sun down). The show then takes us to Dorne, Ellaria with one of her daughter is in the same clothes as they were in last season. So it is the same day from the final season, only that it just got brighter instead of darker. They get the message about Myrcella, then Doran is killed. Next Trystane is killed (who is seen painting the stone that is put on the eyes of the dead, so he must be in Kings Landing for Myrcella's funeral) but suddenly Obara Sand appears.

What's going on? It makes no sense, the first sequence shows Jaime in Kings Landing, the next show Ellaria and Doran talking and it seems like they have just returned from the port.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Prince Trystane was assassinated while on a ship that was at King's Landing some time after the assassination of Prince Doran.**

The episode doesn't really make this clear, because events in Game of Thrones can be quite apart in time, despite being shown in a linear fashion.

You are completely correct. The events in Dorne **do** appear to happen directly after [the last episode of Season 5](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Mother%27s_Mercy).

However since Prince Trystane was on a ship that went to King's Landing, some time must have passed.

How much time? I'm no sailor but the distance between the two looks quite big and I would guess at least several weeks.

[image: Dorne to King's Landing map]

Presumably Obara and Nymeria Sand also sailed to King's Landing just behind Trystane Martell.

**Things are being shown happening at very different times.**

Further evidence for this is that the events at Castle Black all appear to happen in a single day in the episode. I.e. the men watching over Jon Snow and later being confronted by Alliser Thorne.

Comment: Also relevant: Jaime's letter to Prince Doran. You can read it here: http://www.makinggameofthrones.com/production-diary/objects-from-dorne

Comment: The TV show map shows Dorne in Essos, not Westeros.

Comment: That's bizarre if true. Dorne is most certainly in Westeros.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced of my answer after thinking about it. Is it also possible that Prince Trystane was already back in Dorne when he was assassinated? Or was the boat sailing back at the time?

Comment: @RowanFreeman the scene cuts place the ship in Kind's Landing. See my answer here http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/52563/23541

Comment: @cde Nice find. Is there any other way to improve my answer? Is it correct to say that it's docked at King's Landing or was it sailing back to Dorne already? I suppose the sand snakes boarded the boat without alerting guards some how?

Comment: I don't think anyone actually docks at King's Landing. The inlet is too small for most ships. Everyone seems to take row boats out. (makes sense, defensively). The scene in Dorne heavily implies that Dornish guards sided with the Sand Snakes, as only Doran's personal bodyguard attempted to do anything before dying. Everyone else just watched. The only change here is that Trystane was waiting, or about to leave back to Dorne, and that the travel time by ship is likely just a week. The message Jaime sent was by Raven.

Comment: @Chloe That's not true: http://viewers-guide.hbo.com/game-of-thrones/season-4/episode-10/map/location/1/ashemark Dorne is clearly shown in the south of Westeros.

Comment: @TylerH Yes, it is. The TV show introduction clearly shows Dorne a short distance from Meereen, which is in Essos. So Dorne is in Essos. https://sli.mg/SQK177

Comment: @Chloe No, it's not. The introduction graphic is not a to-scale or accurate cartographic depiction of the region. It is for visual effect only. If you want some evidence to back it up, read this article based on a discussion with the show's producer: http://www.hitfix.com/whats-alan-watching/why-doesnt-the-game-of-thrones-map-always-match-up-with-where-the-story-is

Answer (score 9):

Simple explanation, Trystane was sent back by Jaime to Dorne.

[image]

> The Princess Myrcella died by poison on our return journey. I suspect Ellaria and not you, but my sister will demand war. I doubt Ellaria's head will appease her but it's a start, along with your neices. Your son cannot stay in King's Landing so I am sending him back on the same ship.

(This is the letter that was sent to Doran by Jaime, as seen in [HBO's official blog about Making Game of Thrones](http://www.makinggameofthrones.com/production-diary/objects-from-dorne))

I assume there will be a big explanation next sunday. Stay tuned ;)

Comment: The fact that he was painting the stone suggests that he probably was still in King's Landing.

Comment: And in any case, the Sand Snakes still would have to have gotten on that ship at some point. I doubt he was already back in Dorne when that letter arrived and he was killed, otherwise he would have left the ship already. Nevertheless, it's an interesting point.

Comment: That make sense !

Comment: well, reading this, i now think the Sand Snakes are all together in Dorne. Trystane is painting those eyes on the ship who delivered him back home. The letter was delivered ASAP to the king and the prince wanted to finish his work before the ship was on its way back to King's Landing. My explanation below is now just my second favourite.

Answer (score 7):

chronology:

- Jaime sails off dorne heading for Kings Landing, accompanied by Bronn
  (who's completely not seen in E1/S6 by the way), Trystane and dead Myrcella
- two of the three Sand Snakes head also for King's Landing, some time behind Jaime's vessel. The third one and Ellaria stay in Dorne
- asap, Jaime writes to Doran about Myrcella's death. Just this moment Ellaria and the her daughter assasinate Doran and his bodyguard.
- the same moment the two other girls kill Trystane

Ellaria and her daughter wearing 'the same' clothes as on Jaime's departure  isn't a point since all in Dorne seem to wear the same yellow-fashioned sandy style clothes every day as a sign of their dornish identity.

Comment: Also, most people in game of thrones wear the same clothes for weeks. Especially soldiers/killers.