# Balon Greyjoy's assessment of the War of the Five Kings

Tags: game-of-thrones

In Season 6, Episode 2 of Game of Thrones, Balon Greyjoy remarks to Asha that he is the last surviving king from the original five. The deaths of Renly, Joffrey, and Robb are all known throughout the kingdom at this point, but how he does he know of Stannis' death?

Although it's not quite clear how much time passed between seasons 5 and 6, it's seems like it's only been but a few days. Brienne is still outside of Winterfell at the beginning of Season 6 and it's doubtful she would have spent much time outside of Winterfell, waiting in the cold. If the events at Castle Black share the same timeline, then that will also confirm it's only been 1 - 2 days.

Meanwhile, the isle of Pike is hundreds of miles away and the few Iron Islanders that remain on the mainland are located on the coast. It's quite close to winter, meaning few people still travel outside of the keeps. It's even less likely that one of the northerners at Winterfell would travel to the coast and talk to the Iron Islanders. The only other option is a raven, but not a single other person outside of Winterfell has brought up Stannis and Balon Greyjoy seems like the last person Ramsay would notify.

Comment: Now that you mention it, it is surpsiding that Greyjoy would already know of Stannis' death, but I don't think it unreasonable to think that news would have reached the Iron Islands via raven(s). Surely Bolton would want all of the North to know that they still hold Winterfell, and it's not a huge stretch to think that any news widely spread in the North would be forewarded to Greyjoy by allies or spies - or even enemies hoping to demoralize the Greyjoys.

Comment: Timelines are not entirely aligned, whether in the show or in the books. For example, the Night's Watch scenes look as though they take only a single night, however down in Winterfell, Lady Walda goes through an entire term of pregnancy and birth. It's entirely possible that the Bolton's announced Stannis' defeat and subsequent disappearance to the High Lords of Westeros. And don't forget [Raven Mail](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Raven)

Comment: s06e01 starts minutes into the end of S05e10. S06e02 is less than a day afterwards, given the time that Allister gives Davos and the other Jon-loyal crows to surrender. The time frame is about 3 days at best. Not a week.

Comment: @Mooz there is no way that months happen in Winterfell.

Comment: It's implied that the paper Yara is reading that tells Yara and Balon that the Northmen have retaken deepwater motte also tells them Stannis is dead. Yara tells Balon the war is over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The Boltons informed the Greyjoys of the defeat of Stannis Baratheon.**

> Balon Greyjoy seems like the last person Ramsay would notify

I don't think so. Here's why:

- The defeat of Stannis Baratheon is a great victory for the Boltons. Ramsay is known to be boastful of Bolton victories.
- Ramsay enjoys [taunting the Greyjoys](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Balon_Greyjoy#Season_3).
- Ramsay was recently made a true Bolton and not a bastard. Announcing his own victories solidifies this fact more as a powerful opponent.
- It is the [job of Maesters](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Maesters#Function_and_Duties) to inform the world of major events. This appears to be done quickly. There is no reason why the Boltons would stop their Maester from doing this.
- Although Stannis' death is beneficial to the Greyjoys, the Boltons announcing their victory is also a threat to the Geryjoys ("look at what we can do - kill people that claim to be a king").

> it's only been 1 - 2 days

Possibly, but I don't see any reason why it couldn't also be up to a week or so. That's plenty of time for a raven to get to Pyke.

Comment: s06e01 starts minutes into the end of S05e10. S06e02 is less than a day afterwards, given the time that Allister gives Davos and the other Jon-loyal crows to surrender. The time frame is about 3 days at best. Not a week.

Comment: According to [another answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52202/how-did-obara-sand-manage-this/52240#52240) I gave, I believe that things are being showed to the viewer in a non-linear fashion.

Comment: @cde Yes it's max one night at the Wall, however other storylines are progressing much faster.