# Why didn't the Dornish prince go with Jaime Lannister on the boat to King's Landing?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

The prince was promised a seat on the small council. At the end of season 5, I thought he was on the boat with them. But in season 6, it turns out he stayed in Dorne. Why did he stay in Dorne when his fiancé was on the boat and he was given a seat on the small council?

Comment: @Alexandre I disagree. Not the same question at all.

Comment: "Bonus question" has been removed If you have another question, ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple explanation, Trystane was sent back by Jaime to Dorne.

[image]

> The Princess Myrcella died by poison on our return journey. I suspect Ellaria and not you, but my sister will demand war. I doubt Ellaria's head will appease her but it's a start, along with your neices. Your son cannot stay in King's Landing so I am sending him back on the same ship.

(This is the letter that was sent to Doran by Jaime, as seen in [HBO's official blog about Making Game of Thrones](http://www.makinggameofthrones.com/production-diary/objects-from-dorne)), and [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/52305/33629) in my original answer

Comment: This is the same anwser to a relatively different question from the possible duplicate  : How Did Obara Sand manage this

Comment: OK but's it's strange that the prince was caught off guard. I would have though he would have his sword drawn even before he docked in Dorne.

Comment: At that point he was still trying to figure out what happened and how come he just lost his lover. I don't think he understood what happened at all.

Comment: @Chloe he's a sheltered teenager, who doesn't expect to be attacked by his own people in the city where his father rules.

Comment: Exactly, I would even add that this little guy was just a prince living the prince life, he was in love and to him that's all that mattered. He didn't have a single chance to do anything or see anything coming.

Answer (score 2):

**Clarification:** Trystane did leave Dorne on the large ship, along with his fiancé Mrycella and Jaime. They arrived at King's Landing, where a row boat was sent to pick up Jaime and Mrycella. Trystane stayed on the ship.

---

Trystane was waiting to return to Dorne at Jaime's order/request because King's Landing was too dangerous. At least that's what the note that Jaime sent the Prince of Dorne Doran Martell says (as published on [HBO's official blog about Making Game of Thrones](http://www.makinggameofthrones.com/production-diary/objects-from-dorne)). Jaime knew that Cersei would have Trystane killed for revenge.

[image]

> The Princess Myrcella died by poison on our return journey. I suspect Ellaria and not you, but my sister will demand war. I doubt Ellaria's head will appease her but it's a start, along with your neices. Your son cannot stay in King's Landing so I am sending him back on the same ship.

The reason that Jaime didn't return to the harbor at Sunspear wasn't explained, but the obvious reason is that there was nothing he could do. He would be outnumbered the minute he stepped off the boat and likely be killed instantly.